# B2C Password Reset Policy forces sign in to go into forgot password flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a working Custom B2C Password reset policy.

However, if you do your password reset, then you open a new tab and try to log in, it puts you right into the password reset flow instead of bringing you to the sign in page.

We have 2 applications that use 2 policies for sign in, and this is causing problems.

Comment: Is the sign-in custom? Could you show the policy?

Answer (score 1):

In `<TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">` set the session managmenet to `SM-Noop`.

```xml
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#upgrade-the-page-layout-version

Comment: THis did it! thank you